Movie with an escape necessitating organ removal scene?
American movie, from maybe 6 or 7 years ago?
As for the genre, I would say "very near future sci-fi" like The Island.
I only remember the end of the movie where the two protagonists (a man and a woman, who fell in love with each other) are trying to escape from a huge complex and have to remove body organs to perform the surgeries/removals on each other before getting into a fight with agents on that complex.
In the credit roll, you could hear a jazz song (like one of those Michael Buble's covers - it might even be him singing).

Never let me go? (long shot). It's not futuristic, but the plot looks like the one in The Island.

@Larme Not that one, sadly! Thanks for trying, though ^_~

It reminds me of Repo Men (2010).
Plot:

Set in the near future when artificial organs can be bought on credit,
  it revolves around a man who struggles to make the payments on a heart
  he has purchased. He must therefore go on the run before said ticker
  is repossessed.

The ending scene you were talking about, from Wikipedia,

Remy and Beth break into Union headquarters and fight their way
  through the facility to the Union's database. Using Beth's prosthetic
  eye, they enter and seal themselves inside as Jake and Frank arrive.
  The server's only interface is an organ scanner, requiring Remy and
  Beth to cut themselves open to use the scanner internally, clearing
  their accounts. Frank enters and pulls a gun to kill Remy, but Jake
  kills him with a knife and sets explosives inside the organ retrieval
  unit. The explosion destroys the mainframe, wiping the records of
  everyone who has an account with the Union.

The ending scene from YouTube (warning: content might be inappropriate): 



That's it! Thank you very much <3

Sounds like Repo Man from 2010
The described scene features at the very end.

Honestly, your answer appeared while I was writing my own but +1 anyways.

Please add more details to your answer to convince OP why the movie matches description and it would fetch you more upvotes.
